# Can I use C++11 smart pointers as a message return type in the C++ Actor Framework?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++-actor-framework

When I use a unique_ptr as the return type, I receive compiler error C2280:

```
'caf::detail::tuple_vals<std::unique_ptr<A,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>::tuple_vals(const caf::detail::tuple_vals<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function  include\caf\detail\tuple_vals.hpp   102
```

Here's some example code that illustrates the issue (modified from one of the C++ Actor Framework examples):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "caf/all.hpp"

using namespace caf;
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int a;

    A(int a)
    {
        this->a = a;
    }
};

using a_type = typed_actor<replies_to<int>::with<unique_ptr<A>>>;

a_type::behavior_type a_behavior(a_type::pointer self)
{
    return
    {
        [self](const int& a) -> unique_ptr<A>
        {
            return make_unique<A>(5);
        }
    };
}

void tester(event_based_actor* self, const a_type& testee)
{
    self->link_to(testee);
    // will be invoked if we receive an unexpected response message
    self->on_sync_failure(
        [=]
        {
            aout(self) << "AUT (actor under test) failed" << endl;
            self->quit(exit_reason::user_shutdown);
        });
    self->sync_send(testee, 5).then(
        [=](unique_ptr<A> a)
        {
            if(a->a == 5)
            {
                aout(self) << "AUT success" << endl;
            }

            self->send_exit(testee, exit_reason::user_shutdown);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: All types in messages must be regular, i.e., have value semantics. The runtime only calls the copy constructor when *detaching* a message, which occurs when attempting to get non-const access to a message value with a reference count greater than 1.

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin if I understand what you're saying, then my answer below is incorrect (it just happens to compile). If you extend your comment into an answer, I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CAF requires that each type in a message is *regular*. This implies that it must provide a copy constructor, which `std::unique_ptr` doesn't have. Therefore the compiler complains.

Messages have a copy-on-write implementation. You can cheaply copy a single message, as it just bumps the reference count internally. At any time, you can perform const-access of the message elements. The "write" part of copy-on-write only kicks in if the reference count of a message is greater than 1 *and* you request non-const access. At that point the runtime invokes the copy constructor of the contained type to create a new message.

If CAF would unconditionally perform this copy, independent of the reference count, then it would not be possible to efficiently support data flow programming, where an actor receives a message, modifies its contents, and forwards on to the next stage.

Think of messages as pointer containers: the contained elements are allocated on the free store. Storing a pointer in a message is usually a design flaw. The double-wrapping also stresses the allocator unnecessarily.

Since you can slice messages flexibly, you get away with creating a single message and can then use the contained value in various contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the C++ Actor Framework does allow smart pointers in return messages, but not in the form of `unique_ptr`.

The C++ Actor Framework implementation currently makes a copy of the message and dereferences the `unique_ptr`, causing the compiler error.

Instead of using `unique_ptr`, use `shared_ptr` instead. The reference count will be 2 when modifying the question's example code. I also used a custom delete function to verify that the memory is released as expected despite the creation of a second `share_ptr`.